# angularjs, second call to factory

Tags: angularjs

I have this factory function to read a json file depending on language:

```
medicalApp.factory('getTranslation', function($resource, $cookies, $http) {
    var defaults = $http.defaults.headers;
    defaults.get = defaults.get || {};
    defaults.get['Content-Type']='application/json';

    var values;
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    var lang = userLang.substring(0,2);

    console.log('cookie: ' + $cookies.lang);
    if ($cookies.lang === undefined) {
        $cookies.lang = lang;
    }

    if ($cookies.lang == 'fr') {
        values = $resource('translations/fr.json', {}, {
            query: {method:'GET',headers:{'ignored':'ignored'}}
        });
    } else {
        values = $resource('translations/de.json', {}, {
            query: {method:'GET',headers:{'ignored':'ignored'}}
        });
    }

    return values;
});
```

That one is called from this controller when I load the page:

```
medicalApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $cookies, getTranslation) {
    getTranslation.get(function(data){
        $scope.translation = data;
    });

    $scope.changeLang = function (lang) {
        console.log(lang);
        $cookies.lang = lang;
        getTranslation.get(function(data){
            $scope.translation = data;
            console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.translation));
        });
    };
});
```

But when I call it from $scope.changeLang to change the language it never runs. Why?

Can I not call a factory twice? If not how to I update the language from the other json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Augier is right, your factory is returning a single instance of a Resource.  So the 'If' statement, where you check for the language, only gets executed once.

A simpler way to accomplish what you're trying to would be something like (untested code):

```
medicalApp.factory('getTranslation', function($resource, $cookies, $http) {

    ...

    return $resource('translations/:lang.json', {lang: '@lang'});

});
```

And then let your controller determine which language to use:

```
medicalApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $cookies, getTranslation) {
    getTranslation.get({lang:$cookies.lang},function(data){
        $scope.translation = data;
    });

    $scope.changeLang = function (lang) {
        console.log(lang);
        $cookies.lang = lang; 
        getTranslation.get({lang:lang},function(data){
            $scope.translation = data;
            console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.translation));
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

A factory is a singleton object so is as long-lived as your application and therefore called as many times as possible.

You should wrap all of your methods of the factory like this:

```
medicalApp.factory('getTranslation', function($resource, $cookies, $http) {
    // set up any initialisations here

    var factory = {
        get: function() {
            //implement method here
        }
    }
    return factory
});
```

Comment: does the call look the same, because if I try this everything inside of var factory... is not called?